# Redis as a message broker

Tags: redis

#### Question

I want to pass data between applications, in a publish-subscribe manner. Data may be produced at a much higher rate than consumed and messages get lost, which is not a problem. Imagine a fast sensor and a slow sensor data processor. For that, I use redis pub/sub and wrote a class which acts as a subscriber, receives every message and puts that into a buffer. The buffer is overwritten when a new message comes in *or* nullified when the message is requested by the "real" function. So when I ask this class, I immediately get a response (hint that my function is slower than data comes in) or I have to wait (hint that my function is faster than the data).

This works pretty good for the case that data comes in fast. But for data which comes in relatively seldom, let's say every five seconds, this does **not** work: imagine my consumer gets launched slightly *after* the producer, the first message is lost and my consumer needs to wait nearly five seconds, until it can start working.

I think I have to solve this with Redis tools. Instead of a **pub/sub**, I could simply use the **get/set** methods, thus putting the cache functionality into Redis directly. But then, my consumer would have to *poll* the database instead of the event magic I have at the moment. Keys could look like "key:timestamp", and my consumer now has to `get key:*` and compare the timestamps permamently, which I think would cause a lot of load. There is no natural possibility to sleep, since although I don't care about dropped messages (there is nothing I can do about), I do care about delay.

Does someone use Redis for a similar thing and could give me a hint about clever use of Redis tools and data structures?

*edit*

Ideally, my program flow would look like this:

- start the program
- retrieve `key` from Redis
- tell Redis, "hey, notify me on changes of `key`".
- launch something asynchronously, with a callback for new messages.

By writing this, an idea came up: The publisher not only publishes `message` on topic `key`, but also `set key message`. This way, an application could initially `get` and then `subscribe`.

Good idea or not really?

#### What I did after I got the answer below (the accepted one)

Keyspace notifications are really what I need here. Redis acts as the primary source for information, my client subscribes to *keyspace notifications*, which notify the subscribers about events affecting specific keys. Now, in the asynchronous part of my client, I subscribe to notifications about my key of interest. Those notifications set a `key_has_updates` flag. When I need the value, I `get` it from Redis and unset the flag. With an unset flag, I know that there is no new value for that key on the server. Without keyspace notifications, this would have been the part where I needed to poll the server. The advantage is that I can use all sorts of data structures, not only the `pub/sub` mechanism, and a *slow joiner* which misses the first event is always able to `get` the initial value, which with `pub/sib` would have been lost.

When I need the value, I obtain the value from Redis and set the  flag to false.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One idea is to push the data to a list ([LPUSH](http://redis.io/commands/lpush)) and trim it ([LTRIM](http://redis.io/commands/ltrim)), so it doesn't grow forever if there are no consumers. On the other end, the consumer would grab items from that list and process them. You can also use [keyspace notifications](http://redis.io/topics/notifications), and be alerted each time an item is added to that queue.

Comment: I see the advantage of a list, but suppose I have a very fast processor, it still has to poll ... with a slow processor, your suggestion has the advantage that he always gets the most recent item (in opposite to publish where one has to implement the desired behaviour hinself), but apart from keeping the recent history in the list, this has no big advantage compared to `get`, I think ...

Comment: Ok, updated your answer, I have to check the linked docs ... one moment please :)

Comment: The keyspace notifications seem to be exactly a tool I need: Use the "normal" `get/set` operations to help "slow joiners", but also allow to access the operations via `sub`.

Comment: Great, I will keep checking here in case you need more information, but a mix of keyspace notifications and something else (a list, a string) looks like what you need.

Answer (score 3):

I pass data between application using two native redis command:
**rpush** and **blpop** . 
"[blpop](https://redis.io/commands/blpop) blocks the connection when there are no elements to pop from any of the given lists".

- Data are passed in json format, between application using list as queue.
- Application that want send data (act as publisher) make a **rpush** on a list
- Application that want receive data (act as subscriber) make a **blpop** on the same list

The code shuold be (in perl language)

---

**Sender** (we assume an hash pass)

```
#Encode hash in json format
my $json_text = encode_json \%$hash_ref;

#Connect to redis and send to list
my $r = Redis->new(server => "127.0.0.1:6379");
$r->rpush("shared_queue","$json_text");
$r->quit;
```

---

**Receiver** (into a infinite loop)

```
while (1) {
    my $r = Redis->new(server => "127.0.0.1:6379");
    my @elem =$r->blpop("shared_queue",0);

    #Decode hash element
    my $hash_ref=decode_json($elem\[1]);

    #make some stuff
}
```

I find this way very usefull for many reasons:

- The element are stored into list, so temporary disabling of receiver has no information loss. When recevier restart, can process all items into the list.
- High rate of sender can be handled with multiple instance of receiver.
- Multiple sender can send data on unique list. In ths case should be easily implmented a data collector
- Receiver process that act as daemon can be monitored with specific tools (e.g. [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/))

Answer (score 3):

From Redis 5, there is new data type called "Streams" which is append-only datastructure. The Redis streams can be used as reliable message queue with both point to point and multicast communication using consumer group concept [Redis_Streams_MQ](https://aws.amazon.com/redis/Redis_Streams_MQ/)