# Jobs and Message Queuing using Redis in .net Core

Tags: azure, caching, redis, messagebroker

I was looking at this documentation of using Azure Redis cache for message broker but there is no link to the documentation in that particular section. any help in pointing to the right document.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-overview
i have a requirement to use Azure Redis Cache as message broker.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ehjba.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you need to goto redis.io and then choose a fork for your desired language - for example C#

https://redis.io/clients#c

I think pub/sub is the key for message brokering

https://redis.io/topics/pubsub

Anyway - maybe

[Redis as a message broker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25133260/redis-as-a-message-broker)

helps

Comment: Thank you for the response. looks like we have to go with the same option of forking the code.