# How do I save files to a server different from the server where my ASP.NET API application is on

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, iis-10, windows-server-2019

So I am building a document management system where files are stored, retrieved and managed using ASP.Net Web API. I have achieved saving the files to the application server (that is the same server where the API is hosted) this can be on IIS, Azure App Service or any other hosting provider.

My challenge now is I wish to have a file server, that is a different server where only files will be stored while the API remains on another server. For instance, let's say my API is running on IIS on Server A (1.1.1.1), I don't want to store the files being uploaded to Server A, I have another Server B(1.1.1.2), which I can also configure IIS on, however, all I want to do with it is store the files sent to the API.

NB. Both servers are windows servers.

My most challenging questions now are:

1. Is the scenario I described above possible or achievable? If Yes,
2. How do I configure my ASP.Net API application to send files to Server B and also retrieve those files at a later time.
3. What configurations do I need to do on IIS for both Server A and Server B.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  This is certainly possible but you will need to elaborate on the issue you are experiencing.

Comment: There are common protocols for accessing Windows file shares. That's not really a programming task, so Stack Overflow isn't the proper place to ask about now to set up NFS/SMB/DFS shares.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's is doable.I had a similar challenge. I am a Node Js guy  but I believe this will work for you as well.

You can achieve that by the use of Queuing with Redis or any other memory database.

1. You will have to Configure publishers on the main server. In your case server A and then, configure Subscribers in server B

Here when you send a file to server A, Instead of saving it, You simply send it to server B through the corresponding publisher and server B will receive the task through the corresponding subscriber.

You can learn more [Here](https://code-maze.com/queue-csharp/)

Also, This might be helful [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64254633/jobs-and-message-queuing-using-redis-in-net-core)

Comment: Thanks for your response @onyango. I thought about that too, but how about performance, putting into consideration the fact that some files can be as large as 500MB.

Comment: If storage is your concern, You can use AWS S3 bucket to store your files then save the resource url in your database.

Comment: The server B will have a storage of up to 1TB. So Storage won't be an issue, my major fear is the performance, the speed at which documents can be uploaded.

Comment: The upload performance issue can be negated by adding those tasks that take long to execute to a queue.
The main server receives the tasks, and passes them to the server B.  Server B will do the heavy lifting. Some how like how web hooks works. When the task is done, server B will append the unique url and then notifies the user or  main server.